# SQL BETWEEN with a CASE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, transform

I am having some difficulty getting a case statement to work. I need to run a case statement on a field that has many different characters and conditions. I first need to strip the field of all non-numeric values, and then set a value based on the value of the field, I have been able to write a case statement that does this, but it is extremely slow. This works:

```
CASE
WHEN (SELECT CAST(CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) FROM master..spt_values WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(fieldtoreplace) AND SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path('')) AS xml) AS varchar(255))) BETWEEN 1 and 10 THEN 'MIN'
WHEN (SELECT CAST(CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) FROM master..spt_values WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(fieldtoreplace) AND SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path('')) AS xml) AS varchar(255))) BETWEEN 11 and 25 THEN 'MID'
WHEN (SELECT CAST(CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) FROM master..spt_values WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(fieldtoreplace) AND SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path('')) AS xml) AS varchar(255))) = 26 THEN 'MAX'
ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END
```

However, I was hoping to be able to do something more like below where it only runs the transformation once instead of for each line of the case statement.

```
CASE (SELECT CAST(CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) FROM master..spt_values WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(fieldtoreplace) AND SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path('')) AS xml) AS varchar(255)))
WHEN BETWEEN 1 and 10 THEN 'MIN'
WHEN BETWEEN 11 and 25 THEN 'MID'
WHEN 26 THEN 'MAX'
ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END
```

The actual statement is 41 different cases with various between and equals statements.

Does anyone have a solution for doing this so that the transformation only has to be run once? the table it is running against is extremely large.

Output for both should be:

```
9    MIN
5    MIN
26   MAX
26   MAX
25   MID
44   UNKNOWN
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample adta and desired rsults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, if you don't want to run something multiple times, use `APPLY`:

```
select . . .,
       (case when v.val between 1 and 10 then 'MIN'
             when v.val between 11 and 25 then 'MID'
             when v.val = 26 then 'MAX'
             else 'UNKNOWN'
        end    
from . . . CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ( (SELECT CAST(CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) FROM master..spt_values WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(fieldtoreplace) AND SUBSTRING(fieldtoreplace, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path('')) AS xml) AS varchar(255)))
     ) v(val)
```

Comment: I was able to use CROSS APPLY to do what I was needing. Thanks!